# parsing a curl in the command line

Tags: command-line, curl

I have this:

```
curl -H \"api_key:{key}\" http://api.wordnik.com/api/word.xml/dog/definitions
```

How do I parse this (within the commandline) to make it take whatever's in between `<text>` and `</text>` in this page?

Comment: protip: don't publish your API key online

Comment: whoops! didn't even notice that...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ curl ....... | awk -vRS="</text>" '/<text>/{ gsub(/.*<text/,""); print "->"$0}'

$ curl ....... | awk 'BEGIN{RS="</text>"}/<text>/{ gsub(/.*<text/,""); print "->"$0}'
```

Note, use GNU awk. (gawk)

Comment: I'm getting this: awk: invalid -v option

Comment: I'm getting this now:  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4127  100  4127    0     0   1272      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  3745
Mac5:~ elijahwood$

Comment: I asked you what OS. Linux? solaris? Ubuuntu?  Fedora? etc... I don't know what is 10.6. Its just a number to me.

Comment: Check your awk version. If you don't have gawk, consider installing it: http://gawk.darwinports.com/. Also, check if you are actually getting something back using curl (without awk). Show the curl output in your question